sda5_ript boot disk, how to enter grub recovery mode?
Is there a special procedure to boot into recover mode for an sda5_ript boot disk?

Do you mean an encrypted drive? https://superuser.com/questions/1536669/grub-bootloader-with-root-luks-encryption-only-grub-shell  Or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory You do have good backups?
